# Проиграть mp3 на входящее смс

Tags: android, sms, mp3

Здравствуйте!
пишу программку по обработке смс от банка и появилась идея установить рингтон на смс от банка (прошу прощения за тавтология). но вот как "заглушить" звук по умолчания и проиграть мой звук не знаю. помогите кто чем может.
спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо ловить бродкаст прихода новой смски и в нотификации обработчика установить желаемый рингтон нотификации. Схематично делается так:

1) Устанавливаем перехватчик бродкаста новой смски в манифесте:

```
 <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"
              android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"
              android:enabled="true"
              android:exported="true"
            >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

2) Пишем собственно сам перехватчик класс `SMSReceiver`

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       //blah-blah
   } 
}
```

3) В перехватчике создаем нотификацию:

```
nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.myIcon)
                .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                .setContentText(notificationText)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .build();
        notification.sound=ringToneUri;  //ссылка на наш рингтон
nm.notify(id, notification); //запускаем нотификацию
```

Некоторые части сознательно не описал :) Это чтобы жизнь сахаром не казалось - разбирайтесь.

Вообще прием СМС штука недокументированная...